# How to search more than one word in a single tweet at the tweepy?

Tags: python, search, twitter, tweepy

I need to search for tweets that have a set of words, but when I enter the search terms, they are searched independently.

For example, if I use this following parameter to search for "WORDS = ['amazon fire', 'rainforest fires']", the results are tweets containing 'amazon' or 'fire' or 'rainforest' or 'fires', not a tweet featuring 'amazon fire' and others containing 'rainforest fires'.

```py
WORDS = ['amazon fire', 'amazon Forest', 'amazon rainforest fires', 'amazon blazes', 'amazon burning']
```

I hope the result is a tweet that contains more than one independently searched word. Like a tweet that is 'The Amazon in Brazil is on fire' and not a tweet 'I set my keyboard on fire'

The full code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/zSZfhA02

Comment: Can you post your results?

Comment: Have you considered just using the twitter API, it interprets spaces (`' '`) as `and` and commas `','` as `or`s.

Comment: this post makes it seem like you can use `AND` and `OR` in your queries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737264/tweepy-api-search-doesnt-have-keyword

Comment: { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6c2c88f67543440c4a0af7"), 
    "created_at" : "Sun Sep 01 20:42:39 +0000 2019", 
    "id" : NumberLong(1168262919689310208), 
    "text" : "RT _RMills: The Amazon Is Not Earth’s Lungs\n", 
    "user" : {
        "id" : NumberLong(955684716824420352), 
        "name" : "Ann Zamora", 
        "screen_name" : "annzamoraa", 
        "location" : "Texas, USA", 
        "url" : null
    }, 
    "lang" : "en", 
    "extended_tweet" : "RT _RMills: The Amazon Is Not Earth’s Lungs\n"
}

Comment: @MasonCaiby I will read this post

Comment: @MasonCaiby, yep, but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is right and is working as espected.

But the WORDS you are looking for are in the `quoted_status` or the `retweeted_status`, if exists in the data.

You can read for further informations here :

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json.html#retweet
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json.html#quotetweet

Comment: If I want to get the original tweet, what should I read to get it changed? I could not get any better than the current code.